# Можно ли передавать параметры url при методе POST?

Tags: java, spring, http

Есть набор рест-сервисов, с реализованными методами GET\POST на spring

В ходе разработки возник спор, можно ли передавать параметры url в методе POST

например

```
POST http://localhost:8081/MyApp/product?dealNumber=111x
Body:  <Product>
          <name>drugs</name>
          <cost>100$</cost>
       </Product>
```

Бизнес смысл такой, что под сделкой сохраняют продукт. Иногда, это несколько продуктов, то есть список xml - элементов и у них общая часть - dealNumber.

Корректно ли такое использование HTTP метода POST, идеально если есть ссылка на какую-н статью где явно об этом говорится

Comment: Многие так используют

Comment: Вопрос безопасности. Параметры в юрл остаются открытыми

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko,О какой безопасности речь? Если используется http то всё открыто, если https, то всё закрыто. Разница лишь в том, что браузер в истории сохраняет адрес

Comment: А с чего ты взял, что сервис будет принимать параметры из урл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В части внутренних ресурсов компании, в целом можно оставить и так, главное чтобы внутри сервера было разграничение доступа к информации (если оно необходимо).
Если ведется внешняя разработка, то рекомендую для безопасности подключить взаимодействие с SSL для шифрования информации.